# Does this set of linear equations only have the trivial solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Let $p$ be a prime and $\xi$ a $p$th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
I would like to solve the system of linear equations
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}(\xi^{nj} - 1)x_n = 0, \quad j=1, \dots, p-1
\end{equation}
over $\mathbb{C}$.
I suspect that it only has the trivial solution for every prime.
I thought of computing the determinant
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\sigma \in S_{p-1}} \operatorname{sgn} \sigma \prod_{j=1}^{p-1} (\xi^{\sigma(j) j} - 1)
\end{equation}
and show it is nonzero, but I don't see how.

Comment: Your equation is of the form $Ax=x$, where $A$ is a matrix of complex $p$th roots of one. I think it's a vandermonde matrix, and much is known about its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If$\ x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{p-1}\ $ is a solution of the linear equations, then the polynomial $\ q(y)=$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{p-1}\big(y^n-1\big)x_n\ $, of degree at most $\ p-1\ $, has at least $\ p\ $ distinct roots $\ 1,$$\,\xi,$$\,\xi^2,\dots,
\,\xi^{p-1}\ $.  This is impossible unless $\ q(y)=0\ $.

Comment: I was hoping for such a beautiful and easy solution!

Comment: @lonzaleggiera e presta molto?

Comment: Ma di pel macolato non sono coverto.